# HTML5への変換で使用できない文字は？

Tags: html, html5, xsl, xslt

XMLをXSLTを使用してHTML5に変換しています．使用しているXSLTプロセッサはSaxon 9.1Bです．（古いDITA Open Tooolkitについてくるもの）

```
<xsl:output method="html"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="no"
            doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
            omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

ところがあらぬ文字が混入しているとHTMLへのシリアライズでエラーが出ます．

> [xslt]
>   D:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.7.5-xxxx\plugins\co.xxxx.html\xsl\xslhtml\dita2htm.toc.xsl:194:
>   Fatal Error! Illegal HTML character: decimal 129

この場合は、`<xsl:value-of select="$xxxx"/>`の中に文字U+0081が入っていた場合です．

XSLTによるHTML変換で発生するこのようなエラーを事前に検出し、抑制したいのですが、そもそもHTML5で許容されない文字が何であるかがわかりません．

HTML（もしくはHTML5）で許容されない文字はどこでどのように定義されているのでしょうか？いろいろWebを探してみましたがどこで規定されているのかがわかりません．

参考URL
XSLT throwing Illegal HTML character exception
http://saxon-xslt-and-xquery-processor.13853.n7.nabble.com/XSLT-throwing-Illegal-HTML-character-exception-td5143.html

ご存知の方おられましたら教えてください．

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 入力のバイト列は何らかのエンコーディングで保存されているでしょうから、バイト値の129(=0x81)がUnicodeのU+0081を表しているとは限りません。単に入力のXMLがSJIS等のエンコーディング(XML標準ではUTF-8であるべき)になっているのではないですか?

Comment: @OOPer この事象は客先で実際に発生しています．お客様はXMLエディタ＋CMSでHTMLのパブリケーションを行っています．CMSはUTF-16でXMLインスタンスをチェックアウトします．同じことを再現しようとして、手元で`&#x0081;`をテストデータに入れてこの結果となっています．（手元で作ったXMLインスタンスはUTF-8エンコーデ－ィングですが）

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。「客先で実際に発生して」いるかどうかはあまり役に立つ情報ではありません(不正なXMLを扱える処理系は実際に使われているので)が、「手元で`&#x0081;`をテストデータに入れてこの結果」と言うことであれば、私が想定した状況とは異なるようです。HTML5的にはグローバルに「許容されない文字」はありませんから、個別の構文上の問題と捉える必要があるでしょう。再現可能なXML文書があるのであれば、それを掲載された方がより良いアドバイスが得られるでしょう。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SERE0014` を throw しているのでしょうから、これでしょう：

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#HTML_CHARDATA

> Certain characters are permitted in XML, but not in HTML prior to HTML5 (...ごっそり引用略...) The serializer MUST signal the error.

で、おそらく XML 1.0 でしょうから、要するに U+007F - 9F でしょう。

Comment: おお！まさしくこれですね．出力はHTML5で本来制限はないはずですが、XSLTプロセッサはそこまでは見てくれていないのでしょう．対症療法的ですが、ここで示されている文字を`xsl:character-map`でエスケープすればとりあえず難はしのげます．ありがとうございました．

Comment: `xsl:output`には`@version`属性があるので、もしかしたら最新のSaxonならこれでHTML5を判定してくれるのかもしれませんが、古いSaxonB-9.1では無理なのでしょう．